# Some information about Spring MVC Message Converters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying the Spring MVC Showcase example downlodable from the STS dashboard.

Now I am trying to understand the **Message Converters** section.

In my view I have the following link:

```
            <li>
                <a id="writeString" class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/messageconverters/string" />">Write a String</a>
            </li>
```

This link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: **/messageconverters/string**

This request is handled by the following method of my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/string", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String writeString() {
    return "Wrote a string";
}
```

This method simply return a String inside the body field of the HTTP Response...this is very simple

The problem is that I am not understanding why this example is inside the **Message Converter** section...

What connects this to the message converts topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to note in the example is **@ResponseBody** method parameter annotation.

This annotation can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name). Spring converts the returned object to a response body by using an **HttpMessageConverter**